# Creating Really Big Python lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, crash

I am trying to create image database compatible with cPickle. Initially list is empty. Data of each image in the directory is added as new row to the list. Images are 224x224. Size of images is on average 8KB. After loading around 10000 images my pc hangs. There are no mouse movement. Nothing happens. needs restart. Below is code snippet which does this..

```
cr=csv.reader(open(csv_file,"rb"))
    for row in cr:
        print row[0], row[1]
        try: 
            image=Image.open(row[0]+'.jpg').convert('LA')
            pixels=[]
            pixels=[f[0] for f in list(image.getdata())]
            #pix=np.array(image)
            dataset.append(pixels)
            #dataset.append(pix)
            labels.append(row[1]) 
            del image

        except: 
            print("image not found")
```

I tried reducing size of images to 28X28 and it works. But i don't want to reduce the size of the images. I am using python 64 bit executable. RAM is 4GB. Ubuntu 14.04. I suspect this is happening due to limited stack space, and list is taking more than available stack space. If so, how do i create this huge list? is there any workaround for this issue? My end goal is to create an numpy array with pixel data as its rows. Currently i am converting list into numpy array.. Is there a solution for this problem??

Comment: Could you create a generator which yields a tuple of the label and pixels for each image. So that you never have to actually create all the data in memory at once?

Comment: I can't replicate your problem because I don't have PIL installed. But I think the problem is that JPG is a compressed format, and you are trying to store the uncompressed format, which will be much larger than 8K per image.

Comment: I don't like answers like mine, but in general you should avoid keeping all things in memory. Use generator/open and close files in cycle, not all at once

Comment: You always could forego building you own database format and use shelve from the standard library.... https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html

Comment: @maxymoo Are you saying using other formats will not cause this issue? I have tried just loading these images, without appending data to a list. It did not crash.. I suspect it is an issue with list

Comment: @PaulRooney Could you please explain how a generator using tuple can solve this? can you provide some references regarding this?

Comment: @ssh99 Im not in a position to provide you with an example, but you should look up [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). It will allow you to iterate through the files without storing them all in memory at once. As for the tuple. You are building up 2 parallel lists in your code, so as an equivalent your generator should yield those 2 things instead of appending them to the list. A convenient way to yield 2 things at the same time is a tuple. To see an example of this see the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) equivalent example.

Answer (score 0):

If the data will eventually be numpy array, maybe try using [`numpy.memmap`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html). It works like "normal" numpy arrays, the difference is that the data is actually stored on the disk in binary. Only the requested chunks of array are put in RAM, thus may get rid of your problem.

If the size of data array is determined, you just need to set up the correct dimension when creating a `memmap` object. If not, check out
[`numpy.memmap.resize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.resize.html), and you should be able to create it anyways.

Oh, and there are other solutions such as `PyTables`.
Good luck!